# Copying files from different directory to common directory

Tags: shell

I have many directories which contain `.c` files. I want to copy all `.c` files in different directories to single directory using shell script.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] before long.  What did you try, and why didn't it work?  How are you going to define the directories where the files are stored?  Where is the single directory in relation to all the rest?  Will `find $HOME -name '*.c' -type f -exec cp -t /target/directory {} +` work for you (assumes you have GNU `cp` with the non-standard option `-t` to specify the target directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
find -name '*.c' -exec cp -t /tmp {} +
```

- start will all items in current directory (recursive)
- take items with name ending `.c`
- copy those items to `/tmp`

If you want to avoid conflicts you can add this

```
find -name '*.c' -exec cp --parents -t /tmp {} +
```

[`ref`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find)