# copy images from many directories to a single directory

Tags: command-line-interface

I have a folder with many other folders in it. Within each of those folders is a .png image. I need to go through all the folders and copy the .pngs to a single folder.

I tried the accepted answer on this thread but it gives an error "illegal option --n"

[Copying files from different directory to common directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008585/copying-files-from-different-directory-to-common-directory)

I am using MACOS

Answer (score 0):

If the directories are only one level deep below your main folder and you want every png from every subfolder, a simple

`cp folder/*/*.png outputfolder/`

Will do it. Of course replace folder and outputfolder with your real folder names

Comment: Here is what I wrote. All it does is print "usage" along with the commands for cp. So must be some kind of error?

Comment: cp Assets.xcassets/*/*.png allImages/