# copy files from different directories in unix

Tags: unix, sunos

my version of unix operating system is

```
SunOS 5.11 11.3 sun4v sparc sun4v
```

I've directory structure like

```
./XYZ_002/DIR2/XYZ DIR DIR/Software Library/TAR Files/TAR5240_5_0.tar.Z
./XYZ_001/DIR1/XYZ DIR DIR/Software Library/TAR Files/XYZ_4_0.tar.Z
./ABC_002/Software Library/TAR Files/tar_3_0.tar.Z
./ABC_001/Software Library/TAR Files/tar_file_1_0.tar.Z
```

I am using below command to copy all the .tar.Z file to current directory,

```
find . -name '*tar.Z' -exec cp . {} +
```

however, I get below error when running the command

```
cp: Target ./ABC_001/Software Library/TAR Files/tar_file_1_0.tar.Z must be a directory
Usage: cp [-f] [-i] [-p] [-@] [-/] f1 f2
  cp [-f] [-i] [-p] [-@] [-/] f1 ... fn d1
  cp -r|-R [-H|-L|-P] [-f] [-i] [-p] [-@] [-/] d1 ... dn-1 dn
```

I've looked at below urls but they are not working for me

[Copying files from different directory to common directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008585/copying-files-from-different-directory-to-common-directory)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/342692/how-to-copy-files-from-multiple-directories

perhaps, I am getting this error because there are spaces in the folder names?
any ideas how can this be resolved?

Note: I did cp with -t option but was getting below error

```
  mymachine> find . -name '*tar.Z' -exec cp -t . {} +
    cp: illegal option -- t
    Usage: cp [-f] [-i] [-p] [-@] [-/] f1 f2
   cp [-f] [-i] [-p] [-@] [-/] f1 ... fn d1
   cp -r|-R [-H|-L|-P] [-f] [-i] [-p] [-@] [-/] d1 ... dn-1 dn
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all `.tar` files to be copied from one directory to another,

try this:

```
find *.tar | xargs -I '{}' cp '{}' test/
```

Where `'test/'` is your destination directory.

Hope this helps.

Note: the `xargs` flag is a capital i.